# Is there any way to rotate dcc.dropdown at an angle?

Tags: python-3.x, dropdown, plotly-dash

[image]

As shown drop down button is in the image is rotated. Is there any way to do it?
I looked into https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/dropdown but didn't find anything.

Comment: you can rotate the dropdown by setting the `style` prop or via css using [`rotate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate())

Comment: Thanks @Bae van der Linden. It would be helpful if you can given one example how to use style prop to rotate. I am new to this. Thanks!

Comment: I've rolled your question back, because your update invalidates the existing answer I posted which you accepted. Might be better to ask a new question if you want to do something different now compared to a month ago.

Answer (score 0):

You could use css to rotate the dropdown:

```
.Select {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

The above would rotate all dropdowns. If you want to rotate a specific dropdown
you could add an `id` to the dropdown and change the css to something like this

```
#dropdown .Select {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

Comment: can we have rotated dropdown with lower tab as normal as in second picture of the question